# SSRS 2008 + SSL displays 404 not found

Tags: ssl, reporting-services, http-status-code-404, ssrs-2008

I have SQL reporting services configured to use a secure certificate and when I visit both Reports and ReportManager I get a 404 not found error.

The reporting services logs do not contain any error information.

I am a bit at a loss to know where to start to diagnose this problem, especially as SSRS is not using IIS.

I created the SSL binding using the Reporting Services Configuration Manager;

- IP Address: (All IPv4)
- SSL Port: 443
- Certificate: {the certicate was
  present in the drop down list}
- URL: https://mydomain:444/Reports

What can I check to get this working?

---

Further to this; I also have an IIS site that uses the same secure certificate.  I have found that if I stop the IIS site, reporting services then works.  I need both to be working - does this mean that reporting services needs to have its own secure certificate?

Comment: Did you get this fixed?  I have the same problem but the ssl is working and port 8080 is not.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and had to assign a differnt port for SSRS to use SSL. It can use the same server certificate, but has to be on a different port than is being used for SSL in IIS.  Change your port for SSRS to something other than 443.  You will have to change the web service and report manager URLs in SSRS Config. Mgr.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the Virtual Directories, applying the change and then changing them back.